# ReactJS Header and Footer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, header, footer, materialize

I am trying to create a **Layout** component which would render the **Header** and **Footer**. So that I can later on use the **Layout** like

```
<Layout> ... </Layout>
```

I have used Routing in the Header and Footer, obviously. To do this, I need to use

```
<Router history...
 <Route path...
```

When I do this one after the other(for header and footer: though I feel that this is wrong) in my layout.js. It works. The header and footer are shown in the browser. ***However, they don't work properly***. On refresh the footer vanishes and sometimes both, the header and the footer. I strongly believe that rendering Router one after the other is the reason for this malfunctioning, but I can't figure out the correct approach. Moreover, I don't want to use the following snippets

**header.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router'
import {Navbar, NavItem} from 'react-materialize';

export default React.createClass({
  render(){
    return (
    <div>
      <Navbar brand='logo' right>
        <NavItem><Link to="/Home" activeClassName="active">Home</Link></NavItem>
        <NavItem><Link to="/Sign-In" activeClassName="active">Sign In</Link></NavItem>
        <NavItem><Link to="/Register" activeClassName="active">Register</Link></NavItem>
      </Navbar>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
    )
  }
})
```

**footer.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router'
import {Footer} from 'react-materialize';
import '../../resource/template.css'


class RT_Footer extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
    <div>
      {this.props.children}
      <Footer copyrights="&copy; 2015 Copyright Text"
          moreLinks={
            <Link className="grey-text text-lighten-4 right" href="#!">More Links</Link>
          }
          links={
            <ul>
              <li><Link to="/About Us" className="grey-text text-lighten-3">About Us</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="/Terms & Conditions" className="grey-text text-lighten-3">Terms & Conditions</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="/Help" className="grey-text text-lighten-3">Help</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="/Contact Us" className="grey-text text-lighten-3">Contact Us</Link></li>
            </ul>
          }
          className='example'
      >
        <h5 className="white-text">Footer Content</h5>
        <p className="grey-text text-lighten-4">You can use rows and columns here to organize your footer content.</p>
      </Footer>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
export default RT_Footer;
```

**layout.js**

```
import {Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router'

class Layout extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
      <span>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
          <Route path="/" component={Header}>
           <Route path="/Home" component={Home}/>
           <Route path="/Sign-In" component={SignIn}/>
           <Route path="/Register" component={Register}/>
          </Route>
        </Router>
      </span>
      <span>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
          <Route path="/" component={RT_Footer}>
           <Route path="/About Us" component={About}/>
           <Route path="/Terms & Conditions" component={TC}/>
           <Route path="/Register" component={Register}/>
          </Route>
        </Router>
      </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Layout;
```

Then I simply rendered **Layout** in index.js

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I suggest that you **don't** render the Router component **twice** (I haven't checked but you probably can't).

So, how the Router component works :

- You give the router an history (via the history props), here you use the browserHistory from the same library wich is fine.
- Then you define all the existing routes for your application using the Route component with a path, and the component to load if the browser url match this path property.

Now, in your case I suggest you to do something like that :

**app.js**

```
import {Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router'
import Layout from './components/Layout'
// Import here all the required components used by the router such as SignIn, Register, ...

render(
    <Layout>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={RT_Footer}>
            <Route path="/About Us" component={About}/>
            <Route path="/Terms & Conditions" component={TC}/>
            <Route path="/Register" component={Register}/>
           // Add as many Route components as needed
        </Router>
    </Layout>,
    document.getElementById('react-anchor')
```

Then your layout file should look like this :

**layout.js**

```
import Header from './Header'
import Footer from './Footer'
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Layout extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                {this.props.children}
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And in your Header and Footer component, render whatever you want, to provide link to load the requested component you can use  from react-router or some other way the library offer (see their documentation)

**Edit :**

Careful about route Path, like "Terms & Conditions" is probably not a valid path

Comment: But its still not working in spite of using
    
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Header}>
          <Route path="/Home" component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/SignIn" component={SignIn}/>
          <Route path="/Register" component={Register}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/" component={Footer}>
          <Route path="/AboutUs" component={AboutUs}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>

Comment: @Quentin, I tried to use this answer and received the following error: ```Uncaught Error: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>``` Why it happened? The code is the same, only with <Link> inside <Header />

Comment: Any component including <Link> would need to be nested within <Router>. Maybe try <Router><Layout><Route><Route>...

Comment: @Quentin this is helpful. Worked for me. I am facing one issue here. I have to show the header and footer only when the user logs in. I am able to access the token {this.props.children} but its not accessible in the header or footer. Can you help with the please?